# Javascript: Setting variable to work in attr line

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Kinda of a noob question, can't seem to solve it, but I may just be tired.

What I'm trying to do is insert a PHP variable in to Javascript (Jquery), and then that variable in to an attr line.

The script I'm using to create the variable:

```
$.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name){
    return $.getUrlVars()[name];
  }
});
```

Setting the variable:

```
var searchresult =  $.getUrlVar('s');
```

And then, where I'm stuck, inserting the variable within the line so that'll come out correctly when I send it off to my iframe.

```
  $(function() {

  $("#searchbutton").click(function() {

     $("#theiframe").attr("src","http://whateverdomain.com/index.php?s=VARIABLE HERE WITHIN JAVASCRIPT");
  })

})
```

I know, kinda beginners question going here, but I admit it, I'm stuck.

Comment: Good resource to learn JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#searchbutton").click(function() {
        var searchresult = getUrlVar("s");
        $("#theiframe").attr("src", "http://example.com/index.php?s=" + searchresult);
    })
})
```

There's already [a jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) that parses URL query parameters - really no need to write your own.* Check out the [example page](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/) for parsing query parameters.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>Though it looks like you didn't actually write the `getUrlVars` plugin yourself.</sub>